# C# Editor and Compiler Preference

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

For those of you that are quick to answer some questions, with code snippets. I must say that I have been beaten to the punch a few times because loading up Visual Studio, File -> New Project... does take some time.  Does anyone out there - particularly for those that are contributing answers here - have a good quick editor on Windows that allows you to enter some c# code, compile-it?  Basically - what's the fastest way of writing sample code for you?

Comment: The fastest way is to not be starting Visual Studio all the time - leave it running. Also, there's only one C# compiler.

Comment: I prefer to use a simple text editor precisely to avoid setting up projects all the time. I'm still waiting for an IDE that doesn't require any setup at all.

Comment: @Tronic Your a "programmer", if you can't find the tool you want, then build it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

[LINQPad](http://linqpad.net).

Typing a piece of code into LINQPad is much faster than creating a Visual Studio project, and its object graph is more usable than Visual Studio's Watch window.

I find LINQPad extremely useful for answering on StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't think that using LinqPad to make some quick snippet code makes someone any worse at c#, this is a great tool!

Answer (score 4):

Enough familiarity with the language concepts to write snippets without the help of Visual Studio -- right in the markdown editor.  And you get the 5-minute grace period for free edits when you realize you made a mistake!

Comment: Agree with this. Anything up to 20 lines I'll often write up in the comment box and eyeball for correctness. Usually I can tell if my code is too hairy to verify by sight alone.

Answer (score 4):

I usually keep VS open all the time, but as an alternative, this program is interesting (and lighter weight):  [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)

Comment: I loved the Snippet Compiler idea when I first heard about it on Scott Hanselman's tools list a couple years back, but I thought its startup time was actually pretty bad for something that was supposed to be lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have Visual Studio open with the project "Test" already loaded.

If I'm pretty sure about the code I can post it first, then try to compile it to see if there is any minor adjustments needed to make it run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use an IDE for writing my code snippets here. Straight in the markdown box. Lack of tabs is annoying (I'm considering writing up a greasemonkey script to try and alleviate that - haven't got around to it so far), but it's not exactly *hard*.

If you want to check for syntax errors, you could just use notepad and `csc`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a fairly easy question, I'll write it all from memory straight in the markdown editor without opening anything else.

Otherwise I make use of the [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/).